GORM adding "AND column.id = 1", why?
Im having an issue with GORM on my GIN project.
Please help me if possible.
My issue is:
var class models.Classrom


old_classID = "algorithm"

DB.Model(&models.Classrom{}).Where("class_id = ?", old_classID).Take(&class)

Is being translated to:
SELECT * FROM `classroms` WHERE class_id = `algorithm` AND `classroms`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1

Why did GORM add the classroms.id=1 part? I would like to check if the classrom exists, and for that Im using its class_id not its primaryKey ID (generated by gorm.model).
The struct is:
type Classrom struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ClassID string `json:"class_id"`
}

I tried to use Take() instead of First(), but it produces the same result. The classroms.id is being inserted because of Where(). Is there a more proper way to "check" if the record exists in the database?
Thanks for the attention,

To avoid that have you tried to use the Find method instead of Take or First?

Not knowing that library or Go that much but the capabilities of SQL: Is there a "Count" or "Exists" function you can use?

Could this be the problem: "If the object’s primary key has been set, then condition query wouldn’t cover the value of primary key but use it as a ‘and’ condition. For example:..." 'Attention'-Box of section 'string conditions'

@MarcinOrlowski I did try to use Find(). It does remove the classroms.id condition, but it returns the entirety of the database without filters (it seems I cant use Where with Find).

@Fildor Thank you, it worked. So, the solution is to class.id=0 before the query. I dont know why I did not read that section of the guide. Sorry to take your time.

@Law No worries. You can read that same passage 1000 times and not "see it". Sometimes we just need another pair of eyes. If a dev tells you they never had that happening to them: they are either lying or have started coding yesterday. :D Feel free to write the fix up as an answer to your question. I am really not proficient with Go, so you are more qualified anyway and I just gave you the nudge in the direction.
